# Background Image "Link" in CSS

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I've inherited a large project that already has a large markup base coupled with a short deadline, so a complete rewrite is out of the question. As such, I have an issue that needs to be resolved ASAP:

(Forgive my cryptic shorthand in advance)

I have a header that contains an UL and a DIV.

```
div id="header"
    ul id="nav"
        <a li />
        <a li />
        <a li />
    /ul
    div id="promotion"
        p
    /div
/div
```

I want the background-image (ie., the entire DIV) to be a link, so I added this to the markup:

```
div id="header"
    a id="overlay"
 ...
```

And the CSS for that reads something like this (not the exact CSS, I don't have access to the file while I'm at home):

```
a#overlay {display: block; width: xxx, height: xxx, z-index: -1
```

Now here's the kicker: the UL and the other DIV need to be positioned above "overlay," because they have their own links in them. This works in FF3 and IE8, but not IE6/IE7. I'm looking for a generic solution to this problem that is compatible in IE6/IE7 (and dropping IE6 is not an option, this is a BIG client)

Any suggestions? Here it is in simple terms: header --> link overlay --> ul with links --> other elements on top of link overlay

Comment: How much do you care about code validation? You can't contain block-level elements (e.g. <ul>, <div>) within a link.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the rest of the link--the only thing inside of the link is text.

So... header --> link with text --> rest of the elements. I figured if I had wrapped everything in the link, despite not validating, it would have just made everything link to that specific URL and not any of the other unique URLs within that DIV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE6/7 [does not respect the z-index stacking context](http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2006/01/Explorer_z_index_bug.html) as you'd expect. Have you tried setting a higher index on the child elements of the parent anchor?

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure how IE was handling the z-index. My other mistake was not setting the position of each element in CSS, which is required for z-index.

Answer (score 2):

You could use JavaScript to attach a click handler to that background instead of relying on a link.

```
document.getElementById('overlay').onclick = function() {
    window.location = 'http://www.google.com/';
}
```

Comment: If you do this, make sure and add #overlay{cursor:pointer} to the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [generic solution](http://robertsays.com/repository/background-link/) I came up with after reading the link Tate Johnson provided.

I tested it and can confirm that it works in IE5.5/6/7/8, FF3, Chrome and Safari.

I was overlooking the fact that you need to declare the position of each element if you're going to use z-index. Setting everything to position: relative (except for the link, which is set to position: absolute) did the trick.